# How to get the form ID attribute in a delegate event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, forms

```
$('form[role=form]').delegate( "input[role=submit_button]", "click", function() {
    alert( FORM.ID  ); /// ????????????
});
```

IMPORTANT: without use closest() or parent() ... you know, when you write $('form[role=form]') here you have the element finded ... why to search it newly ???

Answer (score 3):

`this.form.id` should do it ...

***explanation***

All input elements (*`input`, `select`, `button` etc*) that are contained in a `form` tag, keep a reference to that container in the `.form` property.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do whitout search it again....

`alert($(this).closest("form[role=form]").attr("id"));`

Comment: *"You cannot do whitout search it again"* — This is not true.

Answer (score 0):

In that function `this` and `$(this)` will refer to `input[role=submit_button]` if you want a reference to the form you should save it in a variable before calling delegate so:

```
var myForm = $('form[role=form]');
myForm.delegate( "input[role=submit_button]", "click", function() {
    alert( myForm.attr("id")  ); /// ????????????
});
```